# Hoeffding's inequality, number of samples required

Tags: probability, probability-theory, education

I was deriving the number of samples required to qualify certain confidence bounds, at the end I am getting slightly different results from what is stated in my lecture notes.

can anyone explain why log(a)/log2 is interpreted as log (2/a)

thanks
[image]

Comment: You have an error in line #5. There should be $\ln(L/2)$ instead of ratio of logs...

Comment: yes, but how it is ? according log properties division of logs is the same

Comment: $$\ln L=\ln 2 - \frac{2n\epsilon^2}{(b-a)^2}$$

Comment: grate thanks !!!